# R Shiny DT how to set colour of Rows matching a criteria

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have searched and seen a few examples but cannot get it to work on my own (more experience needed) so some help would be amazing - I am using R shiny App and rendering a table
**Example:**

```
A    B    C    D
a1   1    2    3
a2   4    5    6 
a3   7    8    9
```

1. I want to render rows a1 and a2 with a background colour (purple) and a3 (blue)- this data has only 3 categories (a1,a2,a3) but 400 lines - see current code below
2. currently my data table loads a default of 10 rows - how may i set the option for 25 rows by default.

   output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
       Forecast %>%
         filter(grepl(toupper(input$id_select),Name)) %>%
         arrange(Name, Title) 
     })

Comment: You can set`pageLength` parameter to 10. Refer to the [this](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html) link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `formatStyle` to change the color of the rows, here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame(A=sample(c('a1','a2','a3'),10,replace=T),
                   B=1:10,
                   C=11:20,
                   D=21:30)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(

      datatable(data, options = list(pageLength = 25)) %>%
        formatStyle('A',target="row",backgroundColor = styleEqual(c('a1','a2','a3'),c("purple","purple","blue")))
    )
  }
)
```

There are a lot of examples for styling [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html)